# mongoose find() do not return all documents with correct condition

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to find my document with a condition:

```
partRouter.route('/selectable')
.get((req,res,next)=>{
    Parts.find({
        isSelectable: true
    })
    .then(parts => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(parts);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
});
```

My Parts collection consists of 8 documents with `isSelectable: true`, and one document with `isSelectable: false`. The above function only return two documents which match the condition but I expect it to return 8. Did I miss anything? Thanks in advance.

Edit1:
This is what the mongo shell returned with `db.parts.find().pretty()` command, notice that only 3 documents have the isSelectable field, I wonder why it has disappeared in the other documents as all documents should have this field.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae0056b547a845107e1869e"),
        "name" : "table",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 2,
        "orderQty" : 1200,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-25T04:34:51.158Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-27T01:43:25.169Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T07:06:51.862Z"),
        "updatedBy" : "admin"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae0214d547a845107e186a0"),
        "name" : "back",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 2,
        "orderQty" : 1200,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-25T06:33:49.465Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-02T03:00:21.497Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T06:42:10.868Z"),
        "manHours" : 42.742803611111114,
        "processHours" : 3.887528055555556,
        "totalHours" : 3.887528055555556,
        "unitJourneyTime" : 0.24276411855555555,
        "value" : 18036.829175751263,
        "updatedBy" : "admin",
        "machineHours" : 1.945431111111111,
        "isSelectable" : true
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae02aff547a845107e186a4"),
        "name" : "leg A",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 1,
        "orderQty" : 600,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-25T07:15:11.780Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-27T01:43:25.169Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "updatedBy" : "admin",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T09:34:17.429Z"),
        "machineHours" : 2.8672222222222223,
        "manHours" : 31.539444444444445,
        "processHours" : 2.8672222222222223,
        "totalHours" : 2.8672222222222223,
        "unitJourneyTime" : 0.3584027777777778,
        "value" : 25999.971111111114
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae02b07547a845107e186a5"),
        "name" : "leg B",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 1,
        "orderQty" : 600,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-25T07:15:19.419Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-27T01:43:25.211Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "updatedBy" : "admin",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-04-26T06:37:23.163Z"),
        "machineHours" : 2.0464625,
        "manHours" : 22.511087500000002,
        "processHours" : 2.0464625,
        "totalHours" : 2.0464625,
        "unitJourneyTime" : 0.2558078125,
        "value" : 4127.7148625
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae02b0c547a845107e186a6"),
        "name" : "leg C",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 1,
        "orderQty" : 600,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-25T07:15:24.553Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-27T01:43:25.210Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "updatedBy" : "admin",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-04-26T01:53:34.677Z"),
        "machineHours" : 1.9813308333333335,
        "manHours" : 21.79463916666667,
        "processHours" : 1.9813308333333335,
        "totalHours" : 1.9813308333333335,
        "unitJourneyTime" : 0.24766635416666669,
        "value" : 3996.3442908333336
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae02b12547a845107e186a7"),
        "name" : "leg D",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 1,
        "orderQty" : 600,
        "isSelectable" : false,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-25T07:15:30.708Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-26T02:35:34.482Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "updatedBy" : "admin",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T12:27:53.419Z"),
        "manHours" : 57.80443777777778,
        "processHours" : 5.254948888888889,
        "totalHours" : 5.254948888888889,
        "unitJourneyTime" : 0.45042419047619053,
        "value" : 16866.62489972222,
        "machineHours" : 2.6274744444444447,
        "completionDate" : ISODate("2018-04-26T01:52:37.415Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae1725ef0f1375aa9fff3d7"),
        "name" : "seat",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 2,
        "orderQty" : 1200,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-26T06:31:58.689Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-27T01:43:25.211Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "updatedBy" : "admin"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae17269f0f1375aa9fff3d8"),
        "name" : "rail",
        "productId" : "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty" : 2,
        "orderQty" : 1200,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-26T06:32:09.640Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-27T01:43:25.211Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "updatedBy" : "admin"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ae2815be3638c636ebc4722"),
        "name" : "panel 2/8",
        "productId" : "5ae28142e3638c636ebc4721",
        "unitQty" : 1,
        "orderQty" : 400,
        "isSelectable" : true,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-27T01:48:11.143Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T08:54:25.922Z"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdBy" : "admin",
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-04-27T03:01:02.147Z"),
        "machineHours" : 21.803485833333333,
        "manHours" : 79.83438333333334,
        "processHours" : 21.422397500000002,
        "totalHours" : 21.803485833333333,
        "unitJourneyTime" : 5.853030370616114,
        "value" : 1590.3372043560605,
        "setupHours" : 0.38108833333333336
}
```

Below is the result I got from postman (the correct one):

```
[
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae0056b547a845107e1869e",
        "name": "table",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 2,
        "orderQty": 1200,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-25T04:34:51.158Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-27T01:43:25.169Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "startDate": "2018-04-25T07:06:51.862Z",
        "updatedBy": "admin"
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae0214d547a845107e186a0",
        "name": "back",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 2,
        "orderQty": 1200,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-25T06:33:49.465Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-02T03:00:21.497Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "startDate": "2018-04-25T06:42:10.868Z",
        "manHours": 42.742803611111114,
        "processHours": 3.887528055555556,
        "totalHours": 3.887528055555556,
        "unitJourneyTime": 0.24276411855555555,
        "value": 18036.829175751263,
        "updatedBy": "admin",
        "machineHours": 1.945431111111111
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae02aff547a845107e186a4",
        "name": "leg A",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 1,
        "orderQty": 600,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-25T07:15:11.780Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-27T01:43:25.169Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "updatedBy": "admin",
        "startDate": "2018-04-25T09:34:17.429Z",
        "machineHours": 2.8672222222222223,
        "manHours": 31.539444444444445,
        "processHours": 2.8672222222222223,
        "totalHours": 2.8672222222222223,
        "unitJourneyTime": 0.3584027777777778,
        "value": 25999.971111111114
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae02b07547a845107e186a5",
        "name": "leg B",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 1,
        "orderQty": 600,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-25T07:15:19.419Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-27T01:43:25.211Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "updatedBy": "admin",
        "startDate": "2018-04-26T06:37:23.163Z",
        "machineHours": 2.0464625,
        "manHours": 22.511087500000002,
        "processHours": 2.0464625,
        "totalHours": 2.0464625,
        "unitJourneyTime": 0.2558078125,
        "value": 4127.7148625
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae02b0c547a845107e186a6",
        "name": "leg C",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 1,
        "orderQty": 600,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-25T07:15:24.553Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-27T01:43:25.210Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "updatedBy": "admin",
        "startDate": "2018-04-26T01:53:34.677Z",
        "machineHours": 1.9813308333333335,
        "manHours": 21.79463916666667,
        "processHours": 1.9813308333333335,
        "totalHours": 1.9813308333333335,
        "unitJourneyTime": 0.24766635416666669,
        "value": 3996.3442908333336
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": false,
        "_id": "5ae02b12547a845107e186a7",
        "name": "leg D",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 1,
        "orderQty": 600,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-25T07:15:30.708Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-26T02:35:34.482Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "updatedBy": "admin",
        "startDate": "2018-04-25T12:27:53.419Z",
        "manHours": 57.80443777777778,
        "processHours": 5.254948888888889,
        "totalHours": 5.254948888888889,
        "unitJourneyTime": 0.45042419047619053,
        "value": 16866.62489972222,
        "machineHours": 2.6274744444444447,
        "completionDate": "2018-04-26T01:52:37.415Z"
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae1725ef0f1375aa9fff3d7",
        "name": "seat",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 2,
        "orderQty": 1200,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-26T06:31:58.689Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-27T01:43:25.211Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "updatedBy": "admin"
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae17269f0f1375aa9fff3d8",
        "name": "rail",
        "productId": "5ae00563547a845107e1869d",
        "unitQty": 2,
        "orderQty": 1200,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-26T06:32:09.640Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-27T01:43:25.211Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "updatedBy": "admin"
    },
    {
        "isSelectable": true,
        "_id": "5ae2815be3638c636ebc4722",
        "name": "panel 2/8",
        "productId": "5ae28142e3638c636ebc4721",
        "unitQty": 1,
        "orderQty": 400,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-27T01:48:11.143Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T08:54:25.922Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "startDate": "2018-04-27T03:01:02.147Z",
        "machineHours": 21.803485833333333,
        "manHours": 79.83438333333334,
        "processHours": 21.422397500000002,
        "totalHours": 21.803485833333333,
        "unitJourneyTime": 5.853030370616114,
        "value": 1590.3372043560605,
        "setupHours": 0.38108833333333336
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you show your database table?

Comment: is it returing all the 8 parts when you are writing `db.collectionName.find({isSelectable : true})` in the mongodb shell ?

Comment: Just got back to my office, @DanielKmak I have included my current database collection in my Edit1. @Aniketh tried `db.collectionName.find({isSelectable : true})` and only the 2 documents were returned as mentioned before, I think this is because of the isSelectable field is disappeared in some documents for some reasons (see my Edit2).

Comment: @AnikethSaha Sorry for the typo, I meant my Edit1.

Comment: make `isSelectable: { required : true }` in the schema and try filling the datas in collection again and `db.collectionName.find({isSelectable : true})` in mongoDB shell and in the node mongoose query too.

Comment: Thank you @AnikethSaha it works magically! So does it means if I don't make `isSelectable: { required : true }` in the schema, the the isSelectable field will be truncated when I query with the condition?

Comment: Great to that it helped you. As mongodb is object oriented database unlike mysql db which is relational db it doesnt have columns and rows which make each fields usable either required or give null value but each column should have value

Comment: I will put this as an answer and you can mark it ticked so that others can get helped from this

Comment: I see, in hindsight I should make most field required to avoid having to reenter all data (imagine lots of data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `isSelectable: { required : true }` in the schema and try filling the datas in collection again and `db.collectionName.find({isSelectable : true})` in mongoDB shell and in the node mongoose query too.